# cron job + script not run from cron job , while script run on shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, sudo, cron

we have a strange behavior , and I will explain

the following script run successfully on linux machine

```
su - hdfs -c "sudo /home/tasks.bash"

ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
32187 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
39256 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
```

but when we put the script in cron job as the following

```
more  /etc/cron.d/TASKS_JOB

*/1 * * * * su - hdfs -c "sudo /home/tasks.bash"
```

then script not executed  ( script should run each 1 min )

what could be the reason for that ?

Comment: how did you configure the cronjob? `crontab -e`?

Comment: this is cron file under /etc/cron.d

Comment: and the script should be run as user `hdfs`?

Comment: yes as I wrote - su - hdfs -c "sudo /home/tasks.bash"

Comment: is the user allowed to sudo the command without password?

Comment: yes without password , on shell its run successfully

Comment: so why on cron it isn't run as its run on shell ?

Comment: You're running the cron entry as root, switching to the **hdfs** user, then having that user run the script as root??? Can you explain the logic here?

Comment: syntax should be:
`* * * * * <user> <command>`

Comment: please post your answer , its works

Comment: I’m with @ajgringo619 , why isn’t this just:  `*/1 * * * * root /home/tasks.bash` ?